# Show seams only

Tags: uv

Is it possible to hide the model but still show the seams? I have a complex model that I am trying to UV map but am struggling making both sides symmetrical. So it would be useful to see only the seams to check its symmetry.

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

I've fixed this by selecting the lines of a model I want to mark as a seam and then shift - h to hide everything but the selected lines. I can then easily check to see if I missed anything.

To select check seams once they are done, select a seam and chose select similar>seam from the select menu then shift - h to hide all but the selected seams.

Its ironic that after struggling with this for days I discover a workaround after posting.

Comment: So often the way... :D